# Conjugate function of negative logarithm: fault in my reasoning?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

A problem, asked by [Boyd and Vandenberghe (3.36f)](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), is:

> Compute the conjugate function $f^*(y,u) = \sup_{x,t} \{ y^Tx + ut - f(x) \}$  of the negative generalized logarithm for second-order cone:
>   $f(x,t) = −\log{(t^2 −x^Tx)}$ on $\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \mid \|x\|_2 < t \}$

[The solution manual](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) states $dom f^* = \{(y,u) \mid ||y|| < -u \}$.

Well, I disagree, and I don't see why my disagreement is false.

Let $(y,u) \in dom f^*$.

If $u > 0$, then for $x=0$, $y^Tx + ut - f(x) = ut + \log{t^2} \rightarrow_{t+\infty} +\infty$. So $(y,u) \notin dom f^*$ Therefore, $u \leq 0$.

We consider now $u \leq 0$.
If $\exists k, y_k > 0$, then for $z>0$, $x=(\delta_{ki}z)_i$, $t=-2z$,  $y^Tx + ut - f(x) = z(y_k - 2u) + \log{3z^2} \rightarrow_{z+\infty} +\infty$. So $(y,u) \notin dom f^*$ Therefore, $\forall k, y_k \leq 0$.

If $\exists k, y_k > 0$, then for $z>0$, $x=(-\delta_{ki}z)_i$, $t=-2z$,  $y^Tx + ut - f(x) = z(-y_k - 2u) + \log{3z^2} \rightarrow_{z+\infty} +\infty$. So $(y,u) \notin dom f^*$ Therefore, $\forall k, y_k = 0$.

This is quite different. What is wrong?

Comment: There are problems in the second and third case. If $t=-2z$ with $z >0$, does $(x,t)$ belongs to the set given set? By the way, the domain of your $f$ should be $\left\{ (x,t) : \lVert x \rVert_{2} < t \right\}$ -- there is no $^2$ in the norm.

Comment: What is $\delta_{ki}$?

Comment: Thanks @weirdo you got it!

Comment: $\delta_{ki}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)